# Обьясните алгоритм выполнения кода

Tags: jquery, алгоритм

```
function chess(){
  for(var i = 0;i<8;i++){
      for(var j = 0;j<8;j++){
          if((i%2==0 && j%2== 0) || (j%2!=0 && i%2!==0)){
              $("#board").append('<div class="white"></div>');
          }else{
              $("#board").append('<div class="black"></div>');
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Этот код генерирует шахматную доску 8x8, но я не очень хорошо его понял.

Comment: `%2==0` это остаток от деления на 2, другими словами на четных позициях будут белые, на нечетных - черные, но это только на четных строках благодаря `||`. Если уж совсем туго, можно вручную или через отладчик пройти цикл и убедиться

Comment: условие можно упростить до `i%2 == j%2`

Comment: Чтобы понять, нужно во-первых знать как работают простейшие конструкции: ветвление (if), цикл (for), операции - в помощь учебник по программированию. А затем на бумаге трассируете вашу функцию: что будет при i=0 и j=0, i=0 и j=1 и так далее, вычисляете вручную. Можно в уме, тут не сложно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> function chess() {
> ```

Объявляем [функцию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) с именем `chess`, которую потом можно будет вызвать (вот так: `chess()`)

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
> ```

Здесь начинается [цикл](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), код внутри него будет выполняться 8 раз, при этом значениями переменной `i` будут целые числа от нуля до семи.

Затем идёт ещё один цикл, таким образом мы имеем двойной цикл, код внутри будет выполняться 8*8 раз.

> ```
> if ((i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0) || (j % 2 != 0 && i % 2 !== 0)) {
> ```

Это [условие](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), оно проверяет, является ли текущая клетка шахматной доски (на пересечении `i`-ой строки и `j`-ого столбца) белой.

В условии используются операторы [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_()) (остаток от деления) и операторы [`==`, `===`, `!=`, `!==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) (сравнения). Условие можно упростить до `i % 2 === j % 2`.

> ```
> $("#board").append('<div class="white"></div>');
> ```

Здесь сначала получается jQuery обёртка над элементом с [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B/id) `board`, затем в конец этого элемента добавляется новый элемент, с [классом](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) `white` или `black`.

---

В результате выполнения функции в элемент `#board` добавятся 64 новых элемента, классы элементов внутри будут чередоваться. Так что вместо двух циклов можно было бы написать один на 64 операции.

Чтобы получилась шахматная доска, надо добавить какие-нибудь [стили](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics), например такие:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    if ((i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0) || (j % 2 != 0 && i % 2 !== 0)) {
      $("#board").append('<div class="white"></div>');
    } else {
      $("#board").append('<div class="black"></div>');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(8, 20px) / repeat(8, 20px);
}

.black {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот полный код и можно посмотреть что он генерирует.

Ну а для того что бы вам было понятно как оно работает просто посмотрите что из себя представляет цикл [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

И что значит оператор [деления](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) `%`.

```js
function chess(){
  for(var i = 0;i<8;i++){
      for(var j = 0;j<8;j++){
          if((i%2==0 && j%2== 0) || (j%2!=0 && i%2!==0)){
              $("#board").append('<div class="white"></div>');
          }else{
              $("#board").append('<div class="black"></div>');
          }
      }
  }
}
chess();
```

```css
#board{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: green;
  padding: 5px;
}
.white,
.black{
  width:10px;
  height: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.white{
  background: white;
}
.black{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="board"></div>
```